# How to remove row through cell content in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Data Storage Web</title>
    <style>
      table,
      th,
      td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Customer Details :-</h2>
    <div
      style="border-right: 2px solid black; width: 330px; height: max-content"
    >
      Name :- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&emsp;
      <input
        type="username"
        id="UN"
        placeholder="Customer Name"
        style="
          border: none;
          border-bottom: 2px solid black;
          outline: none;
          font-size: medium;
        "
      />
      <br /><br />
      Amount :- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input
        type="number"
        id="UA"
        placeholder="Due Amount"
        style="
          border: none;
          border-bottom: 2px solid black;
          outline: none;
          font-size: medium;
        "
      />
      <br /><br />
      Phone No. :-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input
        type="number"
        id="PN"
        placeholder="Phone No."
        style="
          border: none;
          border-bottom: 2px solid black;
          outline: none;
          font-size: medium;
        "
      />
      <br /><br />
      <button
        style="width: 300px; border-radius: 5px; height: 30px"
        onclick="RecordData()"
      >
        <b
          style="
            font-family: helvetica;
            font-size: medium;
            color: rgb(41, 35, 35);
          "
          >SAVE</b
        >
      </button>
    </div>
    <div
      style="
        /* border: 2px solid black; */
        width: 350px;
        height: 200px;
        margin-left: 350px;
        margin-top: -215px;
      "
    >
      <h2>Edit :-</h2>
      ID :- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&emsp;
      <input
        type="number"
        id="UNIDR"
        placeholder="Customer ID"
        style="
          border: none;
          border-bottom: 2px solid black;
          outline: none;
          font-size: medium;
        "
      />
      <button onclick="removeID()">Remove</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <hr />
    <span>
      <h2>Data :-</h2>
      <table id="DataTable">
        <tr>
          <th>S.No</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Phone No.</th>
          <th>Issue Date</th>
          <th>Due Date</th>
          <th>Customer ID</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </span>

    <script>
      serielNumber = 1;
      function RecordData() {
        var length1 = document.getElementById("UN").value;
        var length2 = document.getElementById("UA").value;
        var length3 = document.getElementById("PN").value;
        if (
          (length1 == null || length1 == "",
          length2 == null || length2 == "",
          length3 == null || length3 == "")
        ) {
          alert("Enter all values first !");
        } else {
          var value1 = document.getElementById("UN").value;
          var value2 = document.getElementById("UA").value;
          var value3 = document.getElementById("PN").value;
          var table = document.getElementById("DataTable");
          var dateObj = new Date();
          var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1;
          var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
          var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
          var dddmmyy1 = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
          var dddmmyy2 = day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year;
          var row = table.insertRow(-1);
          var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
          var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
          var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
          var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
          var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
          var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
          cell1.innerHTML = serielNumber;
          serielNumber++;
          cell2.innerHTML = value1;
          cell3.innerHTML = value2;
          cell4.innerHTML = value3;
          cell5.innerHTML = dddmmyy1;
          cell6.innerHTML = dddmmyy2;
          cell7.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000 + 11111);
          var value1 = (document.getElementById("UN").value = "");
          var value2 = (document.getElementById("UA").value = "");
          var value3 = (document.getElementById("PN").value = "");
        }
      }

      function removeID() {
        var row_remove = document.getElementById("UNIDR").value;
        console.log(row_remove);
        table.deleteRow(row_remove)[6];
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here first I enter value in the first section which would add a new row with respect to my entered data, however every row has its unique customer id generated randomly. I want to remove the row by
entering that customer id in Edit field and clicking the remove button on the edit side, but I am unable to do that through this code, I know its wrong, please correct it.

```
function removeID() {
        var row_remove = document.getElementById("UNIDR").value;
        console.log(row_remove);
        table.deleteRow(row_remove)[6];
      }
```

Comment: Is it pure javascript only? no jquery?

Comment: yes pure javascript.

Comment: Note that you put your table in `span` tag that is incorrect.

Comment: You deleted the other question but it's just as relevant here: you have a megaton of unwieldy and duplicate code there. Here's how to write proper HTML and CSS, and how to handle a form with JS: https://jsfiddle.net/c14fz70g/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function, you have to define what `table` is unless it's undefined.  Also remove [6] right after `table.deleteRow(row_remove);` it's an invalid syntax.

To solve this: You can actually **traverse** to each row, compare the unique **cust_id** with **input** value. If it's the same, get the **row_num**, and then remove the row.

```
function removeID() {
  var cust_id = document.getElementById("UNIDR").value;
  var table = document.getElementById('DataTable');
  if (table.rows.length > 1){
    var row_remove = 0,found = 0;
   
    for (var i=1;i<table.rows.length;i++){
       if (table.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML == cust_id){
        row_remove = i;
        found = 1;
        break;
       }  
    }

    if(found){
      table.deleteRow(row_remove);
    }
    else{
      console.log('cust_id ['+ cust_id+'] not found!');
    }
  }
  
}
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Data Storage Web</title>
    <style>
      table,
      th,
      td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Customer Details :-</h2>
    <div
      style="border-right: 2px solid black; width: 330px; height: max-content"
    >
      Name :- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&emsp;
      <input
        type="username"
        id="UN"
        placeholder="Customer Name"
        style="
          border: none;
          border-bottom: 2px solid black;
          outline: none;
          font-size: medium;
        "
      />
      <br /><br />
      Amount :- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input
        type="number"
        id="UA"
        placeholder="Due Amount"
        style="
          border: none;
          border-bottom: 2px solid black;
          outline: none;
          font-size: medium;
        "
      />
      <br /><br />
      Phone No. :-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input
        type="number"
        id="PN"
        placeholder="Phone No."
        style="
          border: none;
          border-bottom: 2px solid black;
          outline: none;
          font-size: medium;
        "
      />
      <br /><br />
      <button
        style="width: 300px; border-radius: 5px; height: 30px"
        onclick="RecordData()"
      >
        <b
          style="
            font-family: helvetica;
            font-size: medium;
            color: rgb(41, 35, 35);
          "
          >SAVE</b
        >
      </button>
    </div>
    <div
      style="
        /* border: 2px solid black; */
        width: 350px;
        height: 200px;
        margin-left: 350px;
        margin-top: -215px;
      "
    >
      <h2>Edit :-</h2>
      ID :- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&emsp;
      <input
        type="number"
        id="UNIDR"
        placeholder="Customer ID"
        style="
          border: none;
          border-bottom: 2px solid black;
          outline: none;
          font-size: medium;
        "
      />
      <button onclick="removeID()">Remove</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <hr />
    <span>
      <h2>Data :-</h2>
      <table id="DataTable">
        <tr>
          <th>S.No</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Phone No.</th>
          <th>Issue Date</th>
          <th>Due Date</th>
          <th>Customer ID</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </span>

    <script>
      serielNumber = 1;
      function RecordData() {
        var length1 = document.getElementById("UN").value;
        var length2 = document.getElementById("UA").value;
        var length3 = document.getElementById("PN").value;
        if (
          (length1 == null || length1 == "",
          length2 == null || length2 == "",
          length3 == null || length3 == "")
        ) {
          alert("Enter all values first !");
        } else {
          var value1 = document.getElementById("UN").value;
          var value2 = document.getElementById("UA").value;
          var value3 = document.getElementById("PN").value;
          var table = document.getElementById("DataTable");
          var dateObj = new Date();
          var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1;
          var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
          var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
          var dddmmyy1 = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
          var dddmmyy2 = day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year;
          var row = table.insertRow(-1);
          var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
          var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
          var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
          var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
          var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
          var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
          cell1.innerHTML = serielNumber;
          serielNumber++;
          cell2.innerHTML = value1;
          cell3.innerHTML = value2;
          cell4.innerHTML = value3;
          cell5.innerHTML = dddmmyy1;
          cell6.innerHTML = dddmmyy2;
          cell7.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000 + 11111);
          var value1 = (document.getElementById("UN").value = "");
          var value2 = (document.getElementById("UA").value = "");
          var value3 = (document.getElementById("PN").value = "");
        }
      }

      function removeID() {
        var cust_id = document.getElementById("UNIDR").value;
        var table = document.getElementById('DataTable');
        if (table.rows.length > 1){
          var row_remove = 0,found = 0;

          for (var i=1;i<table.rows.length;i++){
             if (table.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML == cust_id){
              row_remove = i;
              found = 1;
              break;
             }  
          }

          if(found){
            table.deleteRow(row_remove);
          }
          else{
            console.log('cust_id ['+ cust_id+'] not found!');
          }
        }
        else{
          console.log('Table has no data.');
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to fine row based on customer id cell:

```
var row = Array.from(table.getElementsByTagName("tr")).filter(t => +t.cells[6].innerText == row_remove)
```

Then you can you need to remove the row from the table:

```
row[0].parentNode.removeChild(row[0])
```

Here is working snippet:

```js
serielNumber = 1;
function RecordData() {
    var length1 = document.getElementById("UN").value;
    var length2 = document.getElementById("UA").value;
    var length3 = document.getElementById("PN").value;
    if (
        (length1 == null || length1 == "",
            length2 == null || length2 == "",
            length3 == null || length3 == "")
    ) {
        alert("Enter all values first !");
    } else {
        var value1 = document.getElementById("UN").value;
        var value2 = document.getElementById("UA").value;
        var value3 = document.getElementById("PN").value;
        var table = document.getElementById("DataTable");
        var dateObj = new Date();
        var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1;
        var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
        var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
        var dddmmyy1 = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
        var dddmmyy2 = day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year;
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
        cell1.innerHTML = serielNumber;
        serielNumber++;
        cell2.innerHTML = value1;
        cell3.innerHTML = value2;
        cell4.innerHTML = value3;
        cell5.innerHTML = dddmmyy1;
        cell6.innerHTML = dddmmyy2;
        cell7.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000 + 11111);
        var value1 = (document.getElementById("UN").value = "");
        var value2 = (document.getElementById("UA").value = "");
        var value3 = (document.getElementById("PN").value = "");
    }
}

function removeID() {
    var row_remove = document.getElementById("UNIDR").value;
    console.log(row_remove);
    var table = document.getElementById("DataTable");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var row = Array.from(rows).filter(t => +t.cells[6].innerText == row_remove)
    if (table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length > 1 && row && row.length == 1)
        row[0].parentNode.removeChild(row[0])
}
```

```css
table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
    <h2>Customer Details :-</h2>
    <div style="border-right: 2px solid black; width: 330px; height: max-content">
        Name :- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&emsp;
        <input type="username"
               id="UN"
               placeholder="Customer Name"
               style="
          border: none;
          border-bottom: 2px solid black;
          outline: none;
          font-size: medium;
        " />
        <br /><br />
        Amount :- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="number"
               id="UA"
               placeholder="Due Amount"
               style="
          border: none;
          border-bottom: 2px solid black;
          outline: none;
          font-size: medium;
        " />
        <br /><br />
        Phone No. :-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="number"
               id="PN"
               placeholder="Phone No."
               style="
          border: none;
          border-bottom: 2px solid black;
          outline: none;
          font-size: medium;
        " />
        <br /><br />
        <button style="width: 300px; border-radius: 5px; height: 30px"
                onclick="RecordData()">
            <b style="
            font-family: helvetica;
            font-size: medium;
            color: rgb(41, 35, 35);
          ">SAVE</b>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div style="
        /* border: 2px solid black; */
        width: 350px;
        height: 200px;
        margin-left: 350px;
        margin-top: -215px;
      ">
        <h2>Edit :-</h2>
        ID :- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&emsp;
        <input min="1" type="number"
               id="UNIDR"
               placeholder="Customer ID"
               style="
          border: none;
          border-bottom: 2px solid black;
          outline: none;
          font-size: medium;
        " />
        <button onclick="removeID()">Remove</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <hr />
    <span>
        <h2>Data :-</h2>
        <table id="DataTable">
            <tr>
                <th>S.No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Phone No.</th>
                <th>Issue Date</th>
                <th>Due Date</th>
                <th>Customer ID</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </span>
```

Comment: Upvoted your answer as it's cleaner and supposedly faster!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you could save troubling the User from typing IDs manually: You could simply add on each row a new button for removing it:

HTML:

```
  ...
  <table id="DataTable">
    <tr>
      <th>S.No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Phone No.</th>
      <th>Issue Date</th>
      <th>Due Date</th>
      <th>Customer ID</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  ...
```

Javascript:

```
      ...
      var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
      var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
      cell8.innerHTML = "<button onclick=\"return removeRow(this.parentNode.parentNode)\">remove</button>"
      ...

  function removeRow(row)
  {
      var customer=row.cells[6].innerText;
      var x=confirm("Sure to remove customer "+customer+"?");
      if (x)
      {
        row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
      }
      return x;
  }
```

(Later, in the same way, you could add another row button for editing, which would load the row's data into the form fields allowing thus the user to edit them and save them back to the table.)